# Prove $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)=x\}$ is closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Given $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous function.
Prove that $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)=x\}$ is closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I totally do not have idea on how to start the proof.
What I know is to prove a set is closed, we can prove that $\operatorname{bd} A\subset A$ or $A'\subset A$ or $A^c$ is open.

So here which property should I choose? And is it $A=\mathbb{R}$? Since this set is a straight line from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Comment: Show that the complement is open.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Can you tell me that what is the complement of this set?

Comment: This isn't a line. $A$ is the set of fixed points for $f$. It is true that if $f$ is defined by $y = x$, then $A = \mathbb{R}$, but this isn't necessarily the case. Consider $f(x) = 2x$. Then $A = \{0\}$.

Comment: Do you know what the complement of a set is?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez What I know for complement of $A$ is a set which contains all the elements that are not in $A$

Comment: Well. What is the complemnt of $A$ then?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Is it $A^c=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|f(x)\neq x\}$?

Comment: Indeed. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez So how to prove it is open? Is it prove $A^c=intA^c$? If yes, how to find the interior point of $A^c$?

Comment: Sequentially closedness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**
Set $g(x) = f(x) - x$.  Can you describe the set $A$ in terms of $g$?  What about $A^c$?

Comment: $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|g(x)=0\}$? $A^c=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|g(x)\neq 0\}$?

Comment: Right.  Notice we could also write the second one as $\{x \mid g(x) \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\}$.  Can you express this in some other way (to take advantage of the way continuity is defined topologically)?

Comment: Up to here, I have no idea already. Do you mean that we need to express it in terms of neighborhoods?

Comment: Just to clarify, what is your definition of continuity? (I'm using the topology definition, which says the preimage of any open set is open.)

Comment: @AlanWang What Strants is saying is this: If $\Bbb R$ has the standard topology (I'm assuming that's the case here), then $\{0\}$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$, right?  What does that mean about $\Bbb R - \{ 0 \}$?  Also, remember that $\{ x \mid g(x) \in \mathbb{R} - \{ 0 \} \} = g^{-1}( \mathbb{R} - \{ 0 \} )$.  So what do we know about $g$?  And what does this imply about $g^{-1}( \mathbb{R} - \{ 0 \} )$ and hence $\{ x \mid g(x) \in \mathbb{R} - \{ 0 \} \}$ (which is $A^{c}$)?  What does that imply about $A$?

Comment: Oh my definition of continuity is in terms of $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, sequence or neighborhood. Ya the property you said is listed as one of the theorem in reference book that I study which says that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous iff $G$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ $\implies$ $f^{-1}(G)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Ah, OK.  In topology, that theorem is actually taken as the *definition* of continuity.  

Anyway, can you see how to express $A^c$ so you can use that theorem?

Comment: Since $\{0\}$ is closed, $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is open. Is it let $G=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  (LaTeX tip: the code `\setminus` gives you the backslash for set subtraction).

Comment: Is is since $g$ is continuous, $g^{-1}(G)$ is open. Hence $A^c=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|x\in g^{-1}(G)\}$ is open. So $A$ is closed. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct.  A slightly more direct method to prove this would be to note that $A = g^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $\{0\}$ is closed, so (by a similar theorem to the one you just used) $A$ must be closed.  (It sounds like you don't have this theorem, though, so no worries).

Comment: Hmm there is a theorem which says that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ iff $H$ is a closed set $\implies$ $f^{-1}(H)$ is a closed set. Do you mean this?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.  I wasn't sure if you would have that theorem or not.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Suppose that $A$ has a limit point not contained in it.  Then apply the fact that, if a function is continuous at a point $a$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = f(a)$ to arrive at a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

We will prove that the complement of $A$ is open. Consider $x\in A^C$. Such $x$ satisfy $x\neq f(x)$. Since $\Bbb{R}$ is Hausdorff, there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ which satisfy $x\in U$ and $f(x)\in V$.

Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}[V]$ is also open and $x\in f^{-1}[V]$ so $W=f^{-1}[V]\cap U$ is open neighborhood of $x$. We can prove that, if $y\in W$ then $y\neq f(y)$ (so $W\subset A^C$). I remain it as your exercise.

---

In fact, more general statement holds: Let $Y$ be a Hausforff and $f,g:X\to Y$ are continuous, then $\{x\in X:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed.